# wrong query result using OOP JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript class defined in my code:

```
MyWebsite.Static.Elements = {

    Validate: {        
        emailSuccess: $("#email_success"),
        emailCodeErrors: $(".verificationErrorText[style*='display: inline;']")
    },
    ...
```

If I call the query directly in chrome console I got the following results:

```
Query: MyWebsite.Static.Elements.Validate.emailCodeErrors
Result: []

Query: $(MyWebsite.Static.Elements.Validate.emailCodeErrors)
Result: []

Query: JSON.stringify($(MyWebsite.Static.Elements.Validate.emailCodeErrors))
Result: "{"selector":".verificationErrorText[style*='display: inline;']","context":{},"length":0}"
```

But if I call the query directly I get the result that I am expecting:

```
Query: $(".verificationErrorText[style*='display: inline;']")
Result: [<div class=​"verificationErrorText" id=​"email_fail_retry" style=​"display:​ inline;​">​Incorrect code, please try again.​</div>​]
```

What's wrong with the above notations?

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you initialize the object. Try to initialize it in the onReady event.